# Stemming a list of words in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, stemming

```html
<html>
            <body>
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <th>label</th>
            <th>rev</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>[ story man unnatural feelings pig...] </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>[ airport starts brand new luxury ...] </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>[ film lacked something couldnt pu...] </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>[ sorry everyone know supposed art...] </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>[ little parents took along theate..]</td></tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

IMAGE-> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2EAK.jpg

My dataframe looks like above, I tried the below code to stem it :

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
ps=PorterStemmer()
da.rev=[ps.stem(word) for word in da.loc[:,'rev']]
```

but it was resulting in the same data frame again, can't point out what went wrong.
Any help will be dearly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: Please share a sample of your data rather than a screenshot, it makes it much easier to reproduce!

Comment: Please excuse me for the noobish response I'm new . I hope the dataframe in the snippet helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your exact code but if each item in the series is a list of strings you could try

`da.rev.apply(lambda x: [ps.stem(word) for word in x])`

Comment: [ story man unnatural feelings pig] got changed to [,  , s, t, o, r, y,  ,  ,  ,  , m, a, n,  , ...] The words didn't stem too

Comment: Try `da.rev.apply(lambda x: [ps.stem(word) for word in x.split()])`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! Should it work similarly for lemmatization?

Comment: Yes, should be the same principle - something like `from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer`, `lem = WordNetLemmatizer()`, `da.rev.apply(lambda x: [lem.lemmatize(word) for word in x.split()])`

Comment: It gives me the same original dataframe without lemmatizing

Comment: Are you sure? A lot of simple words won't lemmatize further...there might be only a few changes

Comment: Okay I see ,although words like 'interesting' ,'feeling' can be expected to change ?

Comment: no, they won't. usually lemmatization is done after stemming. `interesting` and `feeling` don't change, but most plurals will change to singular. Have a look at the NLTK book [here](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html#normalizing-text)